# Is there any reason this simple SQL query should be so slow?

Tags: sql

This query takes about a minute to give results:

```
SELECT MAX(d.docket_id), MAX(cus.docket_id) FROM docket d, Cashup_Sessions cus
```

Yet this one:

```
SELECT MAX(d.docket_id) FROM docket d UNION MAX(cus.docket_id) FROM Cashup_Sessions cus
```

gives its results instantly. I can't see what the first one is doing that would take so much longer - I mean they both simply check the same two lists of numbers for the greatest one and return them. What else could it be doing that I can't see?

I'm using jet SQL on an MS Access database via Java.

Comment: `jet SQL on an MS Access` <-- My eyes! The goggles! They do nothing!

Comment: I'm guessing you mean that jet is a somewhat inadequate technology. As you can tell I am a beginner self-teaching my way around in the dark - if you could elaborate a little on this comment I would appreciate it as it may help me understand the magnitude/sanity of the task I am undertaking.

Answer (score 13):

the first one is doing a cross join between 2 tables while the second one is not.
that's all there is to it.

Comment: OK. So a comma implies a cross join. Thanks to all who took the time to point that out. Will spend more time with the "beggining sql" books now.

Comment: The comma implies a join, it is a cross join only because there is no where clause to join the tables.

Answer (score 9):

The first one uses Cartesian product to form a source data, which means that every row from the first table is paired with each row from the second one. After that, it searches the source to find out the max values from the columns.

The second doesn't join tables. It just find max from the fist table and the max one from the second table and than returns two rows.

Answer (score 3):

The first query makes a cross join between the tables before getting the maximums, that means that each record in one table is joined with every record in the other table.

If you have two tables with 1000 items each, you get a result with 1000000 items to go through to find the maximums.